# Meaning of the expression "Ain't no trip we can't get past"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

"Ain't no trip we can't get past"

Does anybody here know what it means?

This expression sort of resembles a saying in Spanish that goes something like this: "there is neither a sickness which lasts a hundred years nor an individual which can endure it".

Is my inference right or am I dead wrong here?

It seems to me that the expression is question is not a well-established one. I read/learnt it a long time ago [here](http://www.noapologiespress.com/thatbastardsez/Rantings/ranting17.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that ain't no idiom.

See **[trip](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trip)**  (TFD)

**6.** *Slang*
**b.** A certain way of life or situation: *"deny that his reclusiveness is some sort of deliberate star trip" (Patricia Bosworth).*

"Ain't no trip we can't get past," there's no situation that we cannot overcome, or sort of.

Comment: I would think it's actually talking about definition 5 "a. A hallucinatory experience induced by a psychedelic drug", but with the same meaning that you mention

Comment: I assumed that it was "trip" as in "journey", myself.

Comment: Thanks to y'all for leaving your answers and/or comments!